# The use of 'hacer a' in Cortazar

Tags: traducción, gramática, argentina, literatura

I was struggling to understand the meaning of this sentence, taken from the initial part of the short writing 'Del sentimiento de no estar del todo', which features in 'La vuelta al día en ochenta mundos' by J. Cortázar.

Can anyone clarify whether the sentence 'hace al poeta' is to be understood as intransitive, something like "this union that fits the poet...", or transitively, such as "this juxtaposition, which creates the poet...", or else?

> Esto puede entenderse metafóricamente pero apunta en todo caso a un
> temperamento que no ha renunciado a la visión pueril como precio de la
> visión adulta, y esa yuxtaposición que hace al poeta y quizá al
> criminal, y también al cronopio y al humorista (cuestión de dosis
> diferentes, de acentuación aguda o esdrújula, de elecciones: ahora
> juego, ahora mato) se manifiesta en el sentimiento de no estar del
> todo en cualquiera de las estructuras, de las telas que arma la vida y
> en las que somos a la vez araña y mosca.

Relevant refs from RAE dictionary for 'hacer':

41. intr. Referirse a, concernir, afectar. Por lo que hace al dinero, no te preocupes.
42. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Corresponder, concordar, venir bien con otra. Aquello hace aquí bien. Esto no hace con aquello. Llave que hace a ambas cerraduras.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think both interpretations, "concern" and "create", are necessarily mutually exclusive.

Personally, I'm not familiar with acceptation (42) and would be inclined to interpret "hacer a" as "being typical of" (a combination of "concern" and "create"). The related phrase that comes to mind is: "El hábito no hace al monje" (The habit does not make the monk).

The overlapping of those two personality traits mentioned in the text is said to be typical of different kinds of individuals.

Comment: acepción is a meaning

Answer (score 1):

**hacer a en la RAE**

intr. **Referirse a, concernir, *afectar*. Por lo que hace al dinero, no te preocupes.**

intr. Dicho de una cosa: *Corresponder*, concordar, *venir bien con otra*.

- la yuxtaposicion de "la visión pueril como precio de la visión adulta"

[...]y *esa yuxtaposición* que hace al poeta y quizá al criminal, y también al cronopio y al humorista [...] ***se manifiesta* en el sentimiento de no estar del todo en cualquiera de las estructuras,de las telas que arma la vida y en las que somos a la vez araña y mosca**

[...]and this juxtaposition that affects the poet and maybe the criminal, and also the *cronopio* (fun-loving off-beats) and the humorist is manifested in the feeling of not being wholly in any of these structures, the webs life weaves in which we are spider and fly at the same time.

hace a here could be: affects or matches [corresponder]

The translation has to go with: se manifiesta

I don't think this juxtaposition *makes* the poet and criminal. *It's the poet and criminal who have this disposition.*

[[Re the term cronopio

> Cuenta la historia que el cronopio mayor, Julio Cortázar, se encontró
> con estos seres “verdes y húmedos” en el entreacto de un concierto de
> Ígor Stravinski en el teatro des Champs-Élysées, quizás en el año
> 1952.
>
> Son personajes indefinibles, según el propio Cortazar, muy cómicos,
> divertidos, amigos y que tienen conductas similares a los artistas,
> poetas, que viven un poco al margen de las cosas. Despreocupados de lo
> que pueda haber sucedido alguna vez, o si la persona que tienen al
> lado es el principe de Gales o quien sea, así van los cronopios por la
> vida.]]

[¿QUÉ ES UN CRONOPIO?_Hear Cortázar explain it](https://doscronopios.com.ar/que-es-un-cronopio/)

Comment: That's what makes most sense to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

This meaning is clearly transitive, and can be translated into English as just `makes` or `makes up`. You are talking about the traits that make someone or something. It is very much the same meaning as in *overcoming the difficulties will make you a man*. In this case:

> [...] and this juxtaposition that makes a poet, and maybe a criminal, and also a cronopio or a humorist [...]

Also, bear in mind that *cronopio* is one of the many words that Cortázar made up himself; you will not find it in any dictionary.

Comment: That's also what the only published English translation I know of does (Thomas Christensen, published by North Point Press in 1986).